# How to properly update stellar-xdr and recreate docker image of stellar-horizon?

Tags: stellar-core, transactions, horizon

I want to increase the memo field from 28 bytes by changing this line in Stellar-transaction.x for my private network:

MEMO_TEXT: string text<28>.

I am able to pull the stellar-go repo into my local folder and change this file. But, I am unsure about how I should go about rebuilding stellar-core and horizon to use this text size. Specifically, I want to rebuild my own docker image (like in https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon) to use this updated folder and then redeploy it on my own server.

What are the proper build steps I should take to make this change and deploy it on my server? If there is documentation on how to rebuild the docker image that would be well appreciated.